# Confusing unreachable pattern error

Tags: rust

I encountered a very confusing error message from the Rust compiler when using the `match` statement.

```
enum Name {
    Known,
}

fn unreachable_pattern(n: Name) -> usize {
    use Name::*;

    match n {
        Unknown => 1,
        Known => 1,
    }
}
```

The Rust compiler complains about an unreachable pattern:

```
error[E0001]: unreachable pattern
  --> src/main.rs:10:9
   |
10 |         Known => 1,
   |         ^^^^^ this is an unreachable pattern
   |
note: this pattern matches any value
  --> src/main.rs:9:9
   |
9  |         Unknown => 1,
   |         ^^^^^^^
```

To *a human*, the real error is that `Unknown` is missing from the definition of `Name`, which is easier to spot when you do not have 40 other variants already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually a known issue at the moment; it is not a bug proper, but rather a quality of implementation issue.

The issue boils down to *irrefutable matches*, i.e.:

```
match variable {
    1 => 2,
    i => 2 * i
}
```

Here `i` is an *irrefutable match*, meaning it *always* matches, no matter the value of `variable`.

---

Well, we have the same issue with that weird report: because `Unknown` is unknown, it becomes a name for a variable in an *irrefutable match*! It is unintended, of course, but it makes perfect sense for the compiler.

The good news is that the compiler starts complaining as soon as the *next* attempted match, so you can easily find out *which* match is irrefutable.

A style-lint [is expected](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues/3070) which would help in this issue, it would report `Unknown` to be an improperly capitalized variable thus underlining that the compiler does not see it as an enum variant.

There are plenty of variations for this bug (see the duplicates), it might also be caused by improperly importing an `enum` for example and thus not having its variants in scope.

Comment: I don't understand why `i` is an irrefutable match? What is irrefutable about it?

Comment: @MikeVella: Irrefutable means that it always matches. And since `i` is no pattern (just a binding), then whatever the internal structure/value of the variable being matched it will always be possible to bind it to `i`.